# OpenVPN Linux client connection fails, but it is normal on Windows

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

## Questions

Hello guys:

I bought a VPS and built my own OpenVPN server. I want to use it to fulfill some of my needs.
Then I configured the client through various channels (including but not limited to official documents, Google, etc.).
It worked fine on Windows, but when I used the same method (same client certificate issuance, same configuration file) to configure my Linux machine there was a problem.
My Linux machine system is Rocky Linux 9.
I first thought that some of my operations were wrong (after all, this is a bit cumbersome and I am not very familiar with it), and then I configured the client of my Windows machine (unchanged, it works normally on Windows) When I got it to use on a Linux machine, I found that the error still persisted.
I checked a lot of information but still can't find the problem.

The system of my VPS server is Ubuntu 22.04, and I use OpenVPN 2.6.9 source code to compile and install it.
My Linux machine (Rocky Linux 9) uses the same set of source code compilation and installation as the server.
Windows uses OpenVPN Connect.

## Related configuration information

### OpenVPN server configuration

The following is my OpenVPN server configuration:

```bash
$ grep -Pv '^$|^#|^;' /opt/openvpn/conf/server_strict-ca.conf 
port 21222
proto udp
dev tun
topology subnet
ca /opt/openvpn/ssl/strict-ca/A_B-chain.crt
cert /opt/openvpn/ssl/strict-ca/server.crt
key /opt/openvpn/ssl/strict-ca/server.key
dh none
server 172.16.110.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-crypt /opt/openvpn/ssl/ta.key
cipher AES-256-GCM
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM
auth SHA384
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
client-to-client
crl-verify /opt/openvpn/ssl/strict-ca/crl/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-info.log
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

### OpenVPN client configuration

Below is my OpenVPN client configuration:

```bash
$ grep -Pv '^$|^#|^;' client.ovpn
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 1.2.3.4 21222  # I have randomly replaced the IP address here.
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nobody  # This item is nogroup in Windows.
persist-key
persist-tun
ca A_B-chain.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-crypt ta.key
cipher AES-256-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM
auth SHA384
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
verb 3
script-security 2
keepalive 10 120
```

## Certificates part

### CAs

Below is the part of my certificate：
A is root CA.

```bash
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in A.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            1f:12:fa:84:28:68:d0:78:e5:90:22:19:2f:60:ce:78:c9:8d:92:18
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: (A.crt, self-signed)
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 18 12:54:52 2023 GMT
            Not After : Jan 18 12:54:52 2033 GMT
        Subject: (A.crt, self-signed)
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (384 bit)
                pub:
                    04:f0:d2:70:b1:dd:88:7d:45:8e:da:7a:30:c7:84:
                    e0:5e:20:c6:86:27:0a:61:69:b1:72:d6:ef:1b:e5:
                    00:21:09:8f:53:6b:a3:43:80:af:10:0e:69:49:d0:
                    fe:f2:fb:2e:48:e3:be:d2:7e:fd:8e:64:32:c1:11:
                    b8:92:81:dd:f8:6e:33:1c:78:d3:ee:98:8a:db:80:
                    3a:57:3e:13:0e:1b:43:dc:25:89:29:b4:11:d4:28:
                    97:d2:bd:22:08:ef:bb
                ASN1 OID: secp384r1
                NIST CURVE: P-384
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                97:21:6A:46:A0:F4:AA:95:D2:9B:6F:86:FB:4D:13:49:FA:59:95:97
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:97:21:6A:46:A0:F4:AA:95:D2:9B:6F:86:FB:4D:13:49:FA:59:95:97

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
         30:64:02:30:7f:3a:2f:85:42:bf:09:df:f7:7b:44:bb:b9:cd:
         18:2f:67:83:14:6a:1f:d6:cb:7c:bd:b1:55:a0:ce:e6:b5:8f:
         d3:cf:11:43:4d:fd:a5:6b:e1:14:d1:35:af:44:3d:f3:02:30:
         74:b4:6a:09:4b:3e:1d:67:ec:2e:69:99:5c:59:d4:19:61:02:
         57:23:e8:a1:33:9a:99:0d:23:7b:88:0a:89:93:a9:da:6a:3c:
         16:fa:76:5c:ef:4f:10:f7:41:c1:e2:c9
```

B is issued by A.
B is a subordinate CA,
which is only responsible for issuing OpenVPN related certificates.

```bash
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in B.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            09:fc:6c:73:25:7d:aa:8b:41:d6:cf:1f:91:68:a4:02:94:98:17:c0
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: (A.crt)
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 13 15:25:55 2024 GMT
            Not After : Mar 14 15:25:55 2029 GMT
        Subject: (B.crt)
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (384 bit)
                pub:
                    04:ef:c9:fa:cb:61:37:54:82:e6:bc:a1:66:e8:be:
                    df:88:08:23:1a:f9:6e:94:29:30:b8:81:29:01:50:
                    be:e1:a9:82:48:fa:28:03:06:2c:8b:65:3d:d0:35:
                    d4:50:10:1b:33:f9:6d:a4:6b:ce:5e:f4:61:6c:31:
                    16:7f:70:a3:08:ae:90:0c:a2:c1:49:ca:e4:6b:80:
                    ea:f4:96:82:e8:ff:bb:f7:9b:d0:2d:37:80:0a:d1:
                    c7:0f:b1:1d:73:aa:2a
                ASN1 OID: secp384r1
                NIST CURVE: P-384
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                AE:50:63:28:D1:4B:01:A4:CC:B3:7C:7B:58:09:1C:19:2B:B7:62:89
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:97:21:6A:46:A0:F4:AA:95:D2:9B:6F:86:FB:4D:13:49:FA:59:95:97

    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:64:02:30:76:ce:62:23:0e:41:df:2a:0c:50:71:93:e6:58:
         1b:4a:06:94:71:e5:a4:4a:a1:a2:9f:ee:aa:5c:0b:8f:5d:83:
         d7:8d:f4:b6:f3:c8:bd:0b:ef:2c:0f:1c:65:76:74:3d:02:30:
         47:74:84:74:e7:b2:10:26:b0:48:35:b4:f7:30:7d:9d:87:a3:
         fd:46:be:fa:18:4b:e7:c5:c3:06:6f:fd:09:ac:cb:25:8b:8c:
         68:81:a6:70:cc:26:ed:68:33:73:4b:f1
```

### OpenVPN server certificate

```bash
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in server.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: (B.crt)
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 13 15:32:58 2024 GMT
            Not After : Mar 13 15:32:58 2028 GMT
        Subject: (Server.crt)
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (384 bit)
                pub:
                    04:ff:91:e0:be:f4:d6:fc:99:f4:c5:9a:05:0e:0d:
                    87:e5:9b:e1:9f:1b:60:b8:b1:12:75:99:7b:0a:c3:
                    27:df:2b:5e:44:b4:5e:f0:fd:ec:27:d4:37:2c:ea:
                    1c:77:e8:06:e3:71:bc:41:1f:fa:82:52:29:4a:33:
                    a6:df:93:9f:63:25:41:e3:99:ce:9b:24:92:97:d4:
                    3b:56:e5:f2:8d:2a:ff:e9:af:6c:75:c5:4c:3f:e4:
                    75:60:b6:e6:c8:aa:ff
                ASN1 OID: secp384r1
                NIST CURVE: P-384
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                96:16:D5:02:57:F3:0D:23:C2:D5:94:11:5A:C5:0F:15:3A:2F:32:B5
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                AE:50:63:28:D1:4B:01:A4:CC:B3:7C:7B:58:09:1C:19:2B:B7:62:89
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Signature Value:
        30:66:02:31:00:bf:80:59:d2:c1:7b:d8:b3:74:e0:e8:ea:2c:
        09:ac:68:22:a6:ba:e9:13:e8:72:00:a4:82:0d:be:fe:30:d1:
        be:2f:46:4f:a2:c1:fb:64:ff:e4:09:1c:1c:9b:70:6d:3c:02:
        31:00:95:84:93:6a:e4:7e:e0:3a:78:ee:14:d9:4c:b1:e6:85:
        ca:22:36:48:60:39:40:38:be:98:0c:43:2d:33:50:00:c4:8f:
        5d:76:96:64:e4:a2:66:ca:f7:1d:43:5a:9d:57
```

### OpenVPN clients certificate

```bash
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in client.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4097 (0x1001)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: (B.crt)
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 13 15:35:37 2024 GMT
            Not After : Jun 13 15:35:37 2024 GMT
        Subject: (client.crt)
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:23:89:52:7c:0e:e7:e5:35:18:65:f6:5b:eb:53:
                    a1:c6:05:ed:c3:94:5f:98:5e:d1:49:bc:4a:48:b9:
                    07:a8:f3:a8:75:d3:00:9a:f4:56:69:08:f9:56:af:
                    ea:7e:d5:38:22:03:d9:4b:5b:fa:b8:1f:c0:ee:8a:
                    5c:bd:e0:46:8a
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                E1:64:90:F7:FB:42:A9:23:FB:E2:9F:91:FB:E1:21:1A:BC:C0:56:2C
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                AE:50:63:28:D1:4B:01:A4:CC:B3:7C:7B:58:09:1C:19:2B:B7:62:89
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Signature Value:
        30:66:02:31:00:cf:51:17:83:0c:24:ba:e5:b8:93:c6:d9:42:
        ae:a8:49:b1:82:72:e3:70:b4:4c:43:df:cb:57:b2:cc:a0:ab:
        0e:39:ef:9b:98:8b:90:55:b0:f6:d7:af:f3:5a:65:44:14:02:
        31:00:b9:e0:88:88:c1:5a:c5:ef:1c:75:38:46:3c:0d:04:fb:
        46:ec:55:ad:fa:79:8b:8e:c3:25:0d:7b:04:e1:84:86:7a:29:
        c8:76:c8:3d:cd:1b:94:f2:95:ce:f2:c2:3a:ce
```

## Logs

The error log I encountered when I connected using `openvpn --client --config cliet.ovpn`
This is client:

```bash
$ /opt/openvpn-2.6.9/sbin/openvpn --client --config client-chain.ovpn 
2024-03-16 15:25:23 Note: Treating option '--ncp-ciphers' as  '--data-ciphers' (renamed in OpenVPN 2.5).
2024-03-16 15:25:23 Note: Kernel support for ovpn-dco missing, disabling data channel offload.
2024-03-16 15:25:23 OpenVPN 2.6.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] [DCO]
2024-03-16 15:25:23 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022, LZO 2.10
2024-03-16 15:25:23 DCO version: N/A
2024-03-16 15:25:23 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]1.2.3.4:21222
2024-03-16 15:25:23 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2024-03-16 15:25:23 UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
2024-03-16 15:25:23 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]1.2.3.4:21222
2024-03-16 15:25:23 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
2024-03-16 15:25:23 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]1.2.3.4:21222, sid=ea0416e2 1f7df5e8
2024-03-16 15:25:23 VERIFY OK: (A.crt)
2024-03-16 15:25:23 VERIFY OK: (B.crt)
2024-03-16 15:25:23 Certificate does not have key usage extension
2024-03-16 15:25:23 VERIFY KU ERROR
2024-03-16 15:25:23 Sent fatal SSL alert: internal error
2024-03-16 15:25:23 OpenSSL: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:
2024-03-16 15:25:23 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
2024-03-16 15:25:23 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
2024-03-16 15:25:23 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2024-03-16 15:25:23 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2024-03-16 15:25:23 Restart pause, 1 second(s)
2024-03-16 15:25:23 SIGINT[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

This is server:

```bash
# Assume the client IP is 5.6.7.8
2024-03-16 15:25:23 5.6.7.8:14601 CRL: loaded 1 CRLs from file /opt/openvpn/ssl/strict-ca/crl/crl.pem
2024-03-16 15:25:25 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (fd=6,code=111)
2024-03-16 15:25:29 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (fd=6,code=111)
2024-03-16 15:25:37 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (fd=6,code=111)
2024-03-16 15:25:53 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (fd=6,code=111)
2024-03-16 15:26:23 5.6.7.8:14601 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2024-03-16 15:26:23 5.6.7.8:14601 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2024-03-16 15:26:23 5.6.7.8:14601 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

I found these sentences in the log of the Linux client:

```
2024-03-16 15:25:23 Certificate does not have key usage extension
2024-03-16 15:25:23 VERIFY KU ERROR
```

Maybe if I solve this problem the whole problem will be solved, but I don't know what it is, can anyone tell me?
Thanks.

## Supplementary content

When I remove the `remote-cert-tls server` option, the Linux client can connect, but I saw someone saying that removing this option seems to cause security risks?

Comment: Indeed both client and server certificates should probably have at least the `X509v3 Key Usage` properties `Digital Signature` + `Key Encipherment` visible in the certificate. Yours don't. It appears that the server doesn't mind, the Windows client neither, but the Linux client does mind. So you have to recreate your certificates (both server and client) with such property. Without knowing *how* you created them, I can't help any further. If the creation doesn't happen on an Unix/Linux system (or at least using the `openssl` command), I can't help either.

Comment: @A.B If you want to see it, I can add it above, but I don't understand which file you want to see. Is it the openssl configuration file used when generating the certificate? Or the configuration file used by the extension?

Comment: Here's one method to do things from scratch: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/setting-up-your-own-certificate-authority-ca/ .